# How can I capture variables inside of Context

Tags: android, service, static, applicationcontext, foreground

I would like to know if the following is possible. I have a foreground service that runs even if the app is killed and it is started with application context. Is it possible to capture static variables inside that application context and keep them alive as long as the service is alive even when the application is killed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you write to a static variable? Sure.  But the foreground service itself can eventually be killed, you can't assume it will run forever.

Comment: So in theory if a have a class that HAS A context and uses that context to start a foreground service than this class will never be unloaded by the DVM and its static variables will be persisted as long as the service that was started is alive?

Comment: Static variables last until the class itself is unloaded.  Which unless something very odd is going on, is the lifetime of the app.  Contexts have nothing to do with it.  However the Android framework has the right to kill and restart a background app (which includes foreground services) at any time.

Comment: So independent of class that static variables are declared in. They should live as long as the application is alive?

Comment: I have eddited my comment

Comment: Yes.  Unless someone tries to unload the class.  Which would be a very unusual thing to do.

Comment: I see. My app runs good on most of the devices but on one plus with oxygen OS my class gets unloaded and static variables with it. Is it possible to stop this behaviour from developers perspective? If it is, how so?